# Add base_path for generating url in Symfony

Tags: symfony, url, routes

I have a quick question, I run my symfony app behind a nginx proxy that redirects all /p/* requests to the symfony and removes the /p/, so Symfony doesn't see the /p/ base path.
I've found a way to add /p/ to assets and it works correctly by just adding a configuration

```
framework:
     assets:
        base_path: '/p'
```

But when I use

```
 return $this->redirectToRoute('routename');
```

I don't see any ways to always add a /p/ on it !
Do you have an idea where this can come from or how I can change this behavior ?

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/external_resources.html#prefixing-the-urls-of-imported-routes

Comment: Hi, 
I've tried it but when I do that I get a 404 on my pages !

Comment: Please show some more code and your request url ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I just made copy of routes (in the app/config/routing.yml) like:

```
app_routes_with_p:
resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
prefix:   /p

app_routes:
resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
prefix:   /
```